# Positioning divs to occupy 50% of width

Tags: html, css

[Here is my attempt as producing my work in a Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/1/)

Here is my CODE.

HTML

```
<div id="updatepanel">
    <div id="accountpanel">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
    <div id="billingpanel">
         <h2>Billing Info</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name:</label>            
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <label>Phone:</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="shippingpanel">
        <h2>Shipping Info</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name:</label>            
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <label>Phone:</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my problem. I have a shopping website and this is an attempt to reproduce the checkout page. I am using a shopping module in a CMS and my code is created dynamically by the CMS. I have limited acces to this but i can tinker with the CSS.

Now what i want is the Billing and Shipping panel to be aligned side by side so the page length is redcued and the end user does not have much scrolling to do. I tried using 'float:left' on the wrapper(updatepanel), but that just did not help.

Comment: [Just add float:left?](http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/3/)

Comment: Live this http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/8/)

CSS:

```
label{
    display:block;
}
#billingpanel{
    width:50%;
    float: left;    
}
#shippingpanel{
    width:50%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
label{
    display:block;
}
#billingpanel{
    width:49%;
    float:left;    
}
#shippingpanel{
    width:49%;
    float:left;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/11/)

Comment: Doing this, you would get a 2% space on the right side of the `#shippingpanel`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to float the `#shippingpanel` and the `#billingpanel`, not the updatepanel. However, you should make sure that you clear the floats afterwards, by adding the `:after` pseudo-element which clears them: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/9/)

```
#billingpanel{
    width:50%;
    float: left;    
}
#shippingpanel{
    width:50%;
    float: right;
}
#updatepanel:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a change to css.One width should be lil less that other

```
label{
    display:block;
}
#billingpanel{
    width:50%;   
    float:left;
}
#shippingpanel{
    width:49.9%;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/13/

Answer (score 0):

I like to set a maximum-width incase content inside stretches the div and messes the layout;

```
label{
    display:block;
}
#billingpanel{
    width:50%;  
    maximum-width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#shippingpanel{
    width:50%;
    maximum-width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The content inside can’t stretch the div, if it’s width is given explicitly.

Comment: you're right.. i think i got that habit from working with old browsers. thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use div tables to do that.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/makla/WeTEp/16/). It is more flexible when designing.

```
<div id="updatepanel">
    <div id="billingpanel">
         <h2>Billing Info</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name:</label>            
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <label>Phone:</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="shippingpanel">
        <h2>Shipping Info</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name:</label>            
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <label>Phone:</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

label{
    display:block;
}
#updatepanel{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
#billingpanel{
    width:50%;    
    display:table-cell;"
}
#shippingpanel{
    width:50%;
    display:table-cell;"
}
```